# Proof matrix is invertible given matrix function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, functions

Given that an $n$ by $n$ matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is defined as:
$$\mathbf{M}_{j,i}=\frac{G(j)}{(j-\alpha)^i}$$
where $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$,  $ G(k)\neq0$ and $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{N}$.
Show that the matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is invertible.


I have tried using row reduction to find a formula for the determinant however it quickly becomes hard to do any operation that simplifies the matrix any further. So far I did: Divide every row by $G(j)$, this gets rid of the $G(x)$ function entirely. Then I multiplied $R_n$ and $R_{n-1}$ by $(n-\alpha)$ and $(n-1-\alpha)$ respectively followed by making $R_n=R_n-R_{n-1}$ which got me a $0$ at the bottom left corner of the matrix however the rest of the terms became too complicated to deal with.

Comment: Have you heard about the Vandermonde matrix before?

Comment: What is $G(\cdot)$ here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we compute determinant, we can  factor out $\frac{G(j)}{(j-\alpha)}$ out from each row and the remaining term is a determinant of a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

Hence

$$\det(M) = \left[ \prod_{j=1}^n \frac{G(j)}{j-\alpha} \right] \left[ \prod_{1 \le i < j \le n} \left( \frac1{j - \alpha} - \frac1{i-\alpha}\right)\right]$$

Hence it is invertible since the determinant is not zero.